Who/What are the "Ladies in Loaves" within Hogwarts Legacy?
In the "THE THREE BROOMSTICKS" shop within Hogsmeade, there's a painting of a lady and text that reads "Ladies in Loaves":


Who or what is the "Ladies in Loaves"?
I tried searching online for references or anything related to it, but I couldn't find anything useful.
